# Domain Still Redirecting Despite Transferring Out of Godaddy

Tags: redirect, dns, route53

I bought the domain nmbrsgme.uk from Godaddy. For a shortwhile, I setup a permanent (301) redirect to my website, numbersgame.uk, which worked as intended.

However, a couple of days ago I transferred the domain to AWS Route53, without removing the redirect. Now, despite the domain being in route53, the redirect is still in place. I can no longer edit the domain in GoDaddy, and I have contacted their support however they said it is no longer in their control as the domain has been transferred out.

Any idea how I can remove this redirect?

I was expecting the url to hang however instead it redirected me as per the old redirect.

Comment: Clear your browser cache.

Comment: I have cleared my browser cache and tested on multiple devices.

Comment: Redirects have very little to do with your domain registrar.  Redirects have to be implemented by a web server.  It is not possible to help you without knowing where your DNS records point  (A, AAAA, CNAME) and what configuration you have on your web server.

Comment: This is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Please [edit] the question to address the points that need to be clarified, then re-ask it on [webmasters.se] and delete it here.